# Setting text to vertical middle inside a div

Tags: html, css

I've read some Q&A about centering some text inside a div but for some reason the examples I try are not working for me.  I'm using some jquery-ui and jquery-mobile css libraries but I don't think that is my problem. The "blue button" seems to align vertically in the middle just fine.  But why don't the two text columns?

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Thread7/tstwwt9p/

```
<br/><br/>
<div class="ui-grid-b" style="display: table;width: 100%;border-style: solid;">
  <div class="ui-block-a" style="text-align:center;">
    <button style="color:#000;background-color:#00b2ee" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" type="button">Blue Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b " style="text-align:center;display: table-cell;">Middle Column Text</div>
  <div class="ui-block-c" style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="ui-link">Sample Link Text</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW, my style='display: table' was something I was trying.  But if I don't need it, that is fine too.

Comment: The blue button isn't vertically centered either.  The container is getting its height from the button, so it only appears centered because the button and container are the same height.

Comment: Think you haven't understood the principle behind centering via tables. You center a `table-cell` inside a `table`. So your "buttons" needed a `div` in a `div`: https://jsfiddle.net/4e7cafme/1/ – currently your markup and the inline styles aren't correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: It is better to use CSS for styling, either in the head section, or a separate file.  Use **div{text-align:center;}** in your CSS.

Comment: In response to fheck, I do have a div inside a div.  Your jsfiddle link has nothing to do with tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<br/><br/>
<div class="ui-grid-b" style="display: table;width: 100%;border-style: solid;">
  <div class="" style="text-align:center;">
    <button style="color:#000;background-color:#00b2ee" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" type="button">Blue Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="" style="text-align:center;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">Middle Column Text</div>
  <div class="" style="display: table-cell;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
    <a href="#" class="ui-link">Sample Link Text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use display: table and table-cells to achieve vertical centering, although it is one way.

I find it simpler to set the height and line-height to the same value when dealing with small single line text, like this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b" style="width: 100%;border-style: solid;">
  <div class="ui-block-a" style="text-align:center;height:60px;line-height:60px;">
    <button style="color:#000;background-color:#00b2ee" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" type="button">Blue Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b " style="text-align:center;height:60px;line-height:60px;">Middle Column Text</div>
  <div class="ui-block-c" style="text-align:center;height:60px;line-height:60px;"><a href="#" class="ui-link">Sample Link Text</a></div>
</div>
```